# What are the causes for these timing issues in the JVM?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, jvm, timing

I've been fiddling around with some sorting algorithms and timing them to see just how effective they are.  To that end, I've created a static class containing a number of sorting algorithms for integers, and another class for timing them and exporting data to csv.

I've started looking at said data, and I've noticed an interesting trend.  My program creates 5 different random arrays for testing, and it take the average of 10 different trials on each array for every sorting algorithm.  The strange thing is that the first array seems to have a significantly longer average time for a few algorithms, but not for the others.  Here's some example data to back it up:
[Dataset 1](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/24472738/result1.png), [Dataset 2](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/24472738/result2.png), and [Dataset 3](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/24472738/result3.png) (times are in nanoseconds).

I'm not sure whether it has to do with certain algorithms, the way I implemented the algorithms, the JVM, or some other combination of factors.  Does anybody know how this type of data happens?

Also, source code for all of this is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/brenns10/sort/src).  Look under the 'src' folder.

Comment: Are the results **[statistically significant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance)**? How many times did you run your experiments? Did you extract a [P-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) using some [statistical hypothesis test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) ?

Comment: warm-up times are pretty common in JVM; most benchmarks run the code for quite a while until the performance stabilizes before trying to compute times. This gives the JVM the opportunity to load all the classes, profile, compile hotspots, etc.  I don't know why the warmup for some of your tests are different than others, but you might want to try changing the order of the sorts and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @rici I'm wondering what else beside the hotspots could have an effect here. The entire source is in one class.

Comment: @amit I definitely didn't do anything that in depth.  I wrote the timing code rather early in the morning,so statistical tests were the farthest thing from my head.  However, if you look at the charts I do believe that there is some obvious significance in the spikes, especially in how repetitive and predictable they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like the effects of just-in-time compilation are present.

To reduce start-up time, when code is first run, it is directly interpreted from the byte code. Only after any particular piece of code has been run several times, the JIT decides it is a critical section and it's worth re-compiling to native code. Then it replaces the method by its compiled form.

The effects of just-in-time compilation is that the start up time is extremely reduced (the entire application does not need to be compiled before it's run) but also the critical sections run as fast as they can (because they eventually are compiled). It looks like the critical section got compiled somewhere within the first evaluation.

I am not sure why some algorithms do not exhibit the speedup from compilation. Most likely it's because they share their critical section with some other previous algorithm. For example, the Insertion sort relies heavily on the `swap` method which got compiled during the selection sort evaluation. Another possible reason lies in noting that mergeSort, which runs consistently, does not rely heavily on function calls, so it does not benefit from inlining. Heap sort, on the other hand relies heavily on the `siftDown` method, which might be difficult for the compiler to inline.

If you mark your `swap` as `final`, it enables the compiler to inline the calls to this method. Since this method is small and it's called often, inlining it (which is a part of the just in time compilation) will help the performance significantly.

To provide consistent test environment, you could [disable just-in-time compilation](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=3827) while running the tests.

Comment: Tried marking `swap` as final, but that didn't work.  Then I used the command line switch in your link to disable JIT compilation, and now the data looks much more [uniform](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/24472738/JIT%20off.png).  Thanks!